# Retrieve object by id using the id of another object in React Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I am trying to build a web app using `React`, `Redux` and `Django REST framework`.
The API provides two different kinds of users. One of them is a model called `Counselor` which has `auth.User` as owner as shown in the code below:

```py
class Counselor(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
                              related_name='counselors',
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # other fields...
```

The `Counselor` class will store the owner id and the API provides and endpoint to retrieve an owner by its id, i.e. `r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$'` and another endpoint to retrieve all the `Counselor` objects in the collection.

Using `react-redux`, I have build a component which will call an action to retrieve all the `Counselor` objects and another one to retrieve the owner given the owner id (of the counselor).

I would like to display only `Counselor`'s `first_name` and `last_name` in the component form. However, the action returns `undefined`.

Below the code and what I have tried to do:

*user reducer*

```js
import {
  // ...
  GET_USER,
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isLoading: false,
  user: null,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    case USER_LOADED:
    case GET_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    // ...
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

*user action*

```js
// GET User
export const getUser = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .get(`/api/users/${id}/`, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_USER,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
    });
};
```

*counselor reducer*

```js
import {
  GET_COUNSELOR,
  // ...
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  isRegistering: false,
  counselors: [],
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    case GET_COUNSELOR:
      return {
        ...state,
        isRegistering: false,
        counselors: action.payload,
      };
    // ...
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

*counselor action*

```js
// GET Counselor
export const getCounselors = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .get("/api/counselors/", tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_COUNSELOR,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

In the `React` component I will call both actions `getCounselors` and `getUser`. When `getCounselors` is called, the `counselors` state is populated, thus I can retrieve the id. However, when `getUser(counselor.id)` is called, the object is `undefined`.

Component code below:

*Form component (point where I called getUser marked with a comment)*

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import { getCounselors } from "../../actions/counselors";
import { getUser } from "../../actions/auth";
import { postAppointment } from "../../actions/appointments";

export class Form extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    date: "",
    start_time: "",
    end_time: "",
    location: "",
    description: "",
    counselor: "",
  };

  static propTypes = {
    counselors: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    postAppointment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    getUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCounselors();
  }

  onChange = (e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const {
      title,
      date,
      start_time,
      end_time,
      location,
      description,
      counselor,
    } = this.state;

    const appointment = {
      title,
      date,
      start_time,
      end_time,
      location,
      description,
      counselor,
    };
    this.props.postAppointment(appointment);
    this.setState({
      title: "",
      date: "",
      start_time: "",
      end_time: "",
      location: "",
      description: "",
      counselor: "",
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      title,
      date,
      start_time,
      end_time,
      location,
      description,
      counselor,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div className="card card-body mt-4 mb-4">
          <h2>Book an Appointment</h2>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            {/* some divs ... */}
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Counselor</label>
              <select
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="counselor"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={counselor}
              >
                <option value="" disabled>
                  Choose...
                </option>
                {this.props.counselors.map((counselor) => (
                  <option key={counselor.id}>
                    {this.props.getUser(counselor.owner)} {/* HERE!!! */}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                Book
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  counselors: state.counselors.counselors,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getCounselors,
  postAppointment,
  getUser,
})(Form);
```

Could you please advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you don't return anything from `getUser` that's why you get `undefined`. The second issue you've tried to get asynchronous data synchronously, that's incorrect. Probably you need both things:

1. make api endpoint to get array of users instead of making many requests to server
2. make this request in `componentDidUpdate`

Actually I don't know the architecture of you app, but it looks a bit weird that you're getting array of counselor from server, then getting id from each object and making request again, but maybe you really need it (anyway pay attention on this)

Comment: Thank you - I will give it a go